# Multiple directives with individual scopes for one element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Can the one element have multiple directives with individual scopes?

Let's say, we have custom directive's child with the controller's scope and any directive (here is "ng-class"):

```
<custom-directive data-model="model">
  <input class="child" data-ng-class="controllerScopeValue">
</custom-directive>
```

Now we want to add extra directive with isolated scope to the child. Something like this:

```
angular.module('core').directive('customDirective', [function($compile) {
  return {
    scope: {
      'model': '='
    },
    compile: function(templateElement, templateAttrs) {
      templateElement.children().attr('data-ng-model', 'directiveScopeValue');
      return function($scope) {
        $scope.directiveScopeValue = 'directive\'s scope value';
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

So, how to keep individual scopes for each directive?

Answer (score 0):

no that is not possible, if you try to do it, you will get error similar to

Multiple directives [myDirective1, myDirective2] asking for new/isolated scope

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JbutdCBsN46dea33qpgr?p=preview)

ignore below dummy code

```
app.directive('myDirective1', ['$document',
function ($document) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false,
    scope : {},
```

and

```
app.directive('myDirective2', ['$document',
function ($document) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false,
    scope : {},
```